# CSS for faded text background

Tags: css

I have an image with a text box overlay in my app.

I'm trying to fiddle with the size of the faded box. It's too tall, but changing the header margin height isn't working to reduce the height.

Can anyone see what needs to be changed to reduce the height of the text box?

Thanks

```
.module {
  background: url(glowcell.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 540px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}
.module > header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.module > header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
.module > header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}
.module > header > h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle instead of posting only your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with just the CSS, can you post more?

My best guess would be this line:

```
  min-height: 540px;
```

Unless you want the minimum height to be 540px, I would just use height. But like I said, it's almost impossible to give a more accurate answer based on only your CSS.